# Facebook's OG scraper is using a different image than in my OG tag

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, react-helmet

I'm building a React app using Gatsby and using the plugin for React Helmet to insert metadata. I just configured all my Open Graph and Twitter tags, but they're not using the images I specified.

For Open Graph I have this, unnecessary code omitted:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';
import desired_picture from '../../images/pictures/other/desired-picture.png';
export default function HeadGlobal() {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <meta property="og:image" content={desired_picture} />
            <meta property="og:image:alt" content='alt text hardcoded' />
            <meta property="twitter:image" content={desired_picture} />
            <meta property="twitter:image:alt" content='alt text hardcoded' />
        </Helmet>
    );
}
```

This component is then exported and rendered as part of my page's layout generator. I know that it's being constructed correctly because I can find the meta tags in the head with dev tools and the site is only one single page on one single URL path (plus a 404).

The problem is that when I put my deployed page into Facebook's sharing debugger, it's getting a completely different image. Where it says that based on the Open Graph tags it constructed the following properties it chose an image with a completely different filepath. I'm 100% sure I typed my filepath correctly. Any ideas? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/)?

Despite opening developer tools and seeing the tags and the rest of the information doesn't mean that they are statically generated and available at the moment Facebook's scraper tries to **scrape** them. If the data is added via JavaScript asynchronously (not exactly at the time you request a page, but a few moments later) Facebook won't see the data hence won't be able to **scrape** it.

The test to ensure that the data is statically generated is to access the source code (right click and "View Page Source") of the page and see if the data is there. If it is, the issue may be in the image or the way is set the meta tag. If not, the data is not available for the crawlers.

With this plugin, you add drop-in support for static metadata:

> With this plugin, attributes you add in their component, e.g. title,
> meta attributes, etc. will get added to the static HTML pages Gatsby
> builds.
>
> This is important not just for site viewers, but also for SEO — title
> and description metadata stored in the document head is a key
> component used by Google in determining placement in search results.

You don't need to change anything (nor the `Helmet` import), just installing the plugin and adding it in the `gatsby-config.js`.